# Turning a character vector to a factor vector with a supplied list of levels creates NAs

Tags: r

I'm sure this has been brought up in SO, but I haven't found questions that specifically address this issue.

I have the following character vector:

```
chr_string <- c("NEW.ENGLAND", "NEW.ENGLAND", "NEW.ENGLAND", "NEW.ENGLAND", "NEW.ENGLAND", "NEW.ENGLAND",
                "NEW.ENGLAND", "NEW.ENGLAND", "MIDDLE.ATLANTIC", "MIDDLE.ATLANTIC", "MIDDLE.ATLANTIC", "MIDDLE.ATLANTIC",
                "MIDDLE.ATLANTIC", "MIDDLE.ATLANTIC", "MIDDLE.ATLANTIC", "E..NOR..CENTRAL", "E..NOR..CENTRAL", "E..NOR..CENTRAL",
                "E..NOR..CENTRAL", "E..NOR..CENTRAL", "E..NOR..CENTRAL", "W..NOR..CENTRAL", "W..NOR..CENTRAL", "W..NOR..CENTRAL",
                "W..NOR..CENTRAL", "W..NOR..CENTRAL", "SOUTH.ATLANTIC",  "SOUTH.ATLANTIC",  "SOUTH.ATLANTIC", "SOUTH.ATLANTIC", 
                "E..SOU..CENTRAL", "E..SOU..CENTRAL", "E..SOU..CENTRAL", "W..SOU..CENTRAL", "W..SOU..CENTRAL", "MOUNTAIN")
```

And I wish to turn it into a factor vector, with a specified list of levels, such as below (note that not all levels in the `levels` vector below appear in the `chr_string` vector above):

```
levels <- c("NEW ENGLAND", "MIDDLE ATLANTIC", "E. NOR. CENTRAL", "W. NOR. CENTRAL", "SOUTH ATLANTIC", "E. SOU. CENTRAL",
            "W. SOU. CENTRAL", "MOUNTAIN", "PACIFIC")
```

Unfortunately, my vector mostly gets turned to `NA` when I attempt the following:

```
factor(chr_string, levels = levels)
 [1] <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    
 [13] <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    
 [25] <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     MOUNTAIN
 9 Levels: NEW ENGLAND MIDDLE ATLANTIC E. NOR. CENTRAL W. NOR. CENTRAL SOUTH ATLANTIC ... PACIFIC
```

I understand that the reason that it creates `NAs` is due to the following (from `?factor`):

> The encoding of the vector happens as follows. First all the values in exclude are removed from levels. If x[i] equals levels[j], then the i-th element of the result is j. If no match is found for x[i] in levels (which will happen for excluded values) then the i-th element of the result is set to NA.

But how do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

As Greg mentioned, the issue is your strings do not match your `levels`. They need to match exactly. To apply this, you could do the following:

```
#starting with user specific data and levels
chr_string <- c("NEW.ENGLAND", "NEW.ENGLAND", "NEW.ENGLAND", "NEW.ENGLAND", "NEW.ENGLAND", "NEW.ENGLAND",
                "NEW.ENGLAND", "NEW.ENGLAND", "MIDDLE.ATLANTIC", "MIDDLE.ATLANTIC", "MIDDLE.ATLANTIC", "MIDDLE.ATLANTIC",
                "MIDDLE.ATLANTIC", "MIDDLE.ATLANTIC", "MIDDLE.ATLANTIC", "E..NOR..CENTRAL", "E..NOR..CENTRAL", "E..NOR..CENTRAL",
                "E..NOR..CENTRAL", "E..NOR..CENTRAL", "E..NOR..CENTRAL", "W..NOR..CENTRAL", "W..NOR..CENTRAL", "W..NOR..CENTRAL",
                "W..NOR..CENTRAL", "W..NOR..CENTRAL", "SOUTH.ATLANTIC",  "SOUTH.ATLANTIC",  "SOUTH.ATLANTIC", "SOUTH.ATLANTIC", 
                "E..SOU..CENTRAL", "E..SOU..CENTRAL", "E..SOU..CENTRAL", "W..SOU..CENTRAL", "W..SOU..CENTRAL", "MOUNTAIN")
levels <- c("NEW ENGLAND", "MIDDLE ATLANTIC", "E. NOR. CENTRAL", "W. NOR. CENTRAL", "SOUTH ATLANTIC", "E. SOU. CENTRAL",
            "W. SOU. CENTRAL", "MOUNTAIN", "PACIFIC") 

#regex to remove periods from your vector of strings
chr_string <- sapply(chr_string, gsub, pattern = '[//.]', replacement = ' ')

#remove double spaces and replace with '. ' string as required by levels
chr_string <- sapply(chr_string, gsub, pattern = '  ', replacement = '. ')

#removing names from the vector
names(chr_string) <- NULL

#as requested; expected result
factor(chr_string, levels = levels)
```

Alternately, just change your `levels`.

Answer (score 0):

The specified levels need to match the character strings.  Your first element is "NEW.ENGLAND", but in the levels you have "NEW ENGLAND" (with a space instead of a dot), so R is not going to match them up.  When creating the factor those need to match exactly, you can use the `labels` argument to change the level codes after the matching, or you can use a second step and call to `levels` to change the labels.

Comment: My attention to detail skills strike again. Sorry for missing this.